# Assign multiple custom liceses to o365 user

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

Below are the app access i need to provide for a user

```
Azure Right Management,Exchange Online(plan 2),Microsoft 365 apps for enterprise,Microsoft Forms (Plan E3),Microsoft Planner,Microsoft streams for O365 E3 SKU,Microsoft Teams,Office for the Web,share Point (Plan 2),Skype for Business Online (Plan 2),To Do (Plan 2)
```

I am using the AzureAD module to do that.
Below is the code i was trying but it is not working

```
Connect-AzureAD 

$UserToLicense = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "Arthur.Dent@xxx.com"

$EnabledPlans = "To Do (Plan 2)"


$LicenseSku = Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Where-Object {$_.SkuPartNumber -eq 'To Do (Plan 2)'} 

$DisabledPlans = $LicenseSku.ServicePlans | ForEach-Object -Process { 
  $_ | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.ServicePlanName -notin $EnabledPlans }
}
 

$License = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense
$License.SkuId = $LicenseSku.SkuId
$License.DisabledPlans = $DisabledPlans.ServicePlanId
 

$AssignedLicenses = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses
$AssignedLicenses.AddLicenses = $License
$AssignedLicenses.RemoveLicenses = @()

Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $UserToLicense.ObjectId -AssignedLicenses $AssignedLicenses
```

i was trying with one (To Do (Plan 2)).

Please need your help to figure out this.

Error:

```
Set-AzureADUserLicense : Error occurred while executing SetUserLicenses 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.Guid'. See the inner exception for more details.
RequestId: 44dfce7b-2cc3-4ab8-b74b-7e321789ccf1
DateTimeStamp: Thu, 18 Feb 2021 15:51:17 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At D:\Azure-licencing_MSOnline.ps1:34 char:1
+ Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -AssignedLicenses $li ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AzureADUserLicense], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.SetUserLicenses
```

Comment: Your error message indicates that what you are running is different than the code you have posted. After the error, can you please post the results of `$error[0].exception.innerexception`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with this line:

```
$LicenseSku = Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Where-Object {$_.SkuPartNumber -eq 'To Do (Plan 2)'}
```

`Get-AzureADSubscribedSku` gets the subscription rather than license. So we cannot use `$_.SkuPartNumber -eq 'To Do (Plan 2)'` here. That results in `$LicenseSku` is null, which is why you get the error `Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.Guid'`.

I assume that you want to assign the To Do (Plan 2) license under O365 E3 subscription to the user. The Service Plan name of To Do (Plan 2) is "BPOS_S_TODO_2" under O365 E3. Then the correct script should be:

```
$EnabledPlans = "BPOS_S_TODO_2"
$LicenseSku = Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Where-Object {$_.SkuPartNumber -eq 'ENTERPRISEPACK'}
```

If the To Do (Plan 2) license you want to assign is under other subscription, you can find its other Service Plan names on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-service-plan-reference).

Warm reminder: To Do (Plan 2) license under Microsoft 365 E3 is also "BPOS_S_TODO_2".

Comment: Thanks for that. worked fine. just need to ask one more thing. there are other licenses also like Azure Right Management,Exchange Online(plan 2),Microsoft 365 apps for enterprise,Microsoft Forms (Plan E3),Microsoft Planner,Microsoft streams for O365 E3 SKU,Microsoft Teams,Office for the Web,share Point (Plan 2),Skype for Business Online (Plan 2). So for each of then i need to provide the Service plan Name..?and also Can i pass multiple plans..? please if you can help me knowing this

Comment: @Sandy Yes. You need to provide the service plan name for each of the plans. You can pass multiple plans from different subscriptions like this: `$MyLicensesList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense] 
$MyLicensesList.Add($License) 
$MyLicensesList.Add($License1) 
$AssignedLicenses.AddLicenses = $MyLicensesList`.